# CKFinder - How to use Connector

Tags: ckeditor, ckfinder

I have installed 3.4.2 of CKFinder into an MVC app that currently works successfully with CKEditor. In the web.config for CKFinder (which strangely wasn't included in the Package Manager Console Install-Package and which I copied over from the zip instead) I see "add key="ckfinderRoute" value="/connector"/>. But there is not connector folder in the install. In another older site here, there is a WebForms project that also uses connector, and has this folder. Do I need this?

I have set up my html with the following:

```
                <script>
                    CKEDITOR.replace('editor11', { 
                        filebrowserBrowseUrl: '/CKFinderScripts/ckfinder.html',
                        filebrowserUploadUrl: '/CKFinderScripts/connector?command=QuickUpload'
                    });
                </script>
```

What else do I need to do to be able to upload files to a server?

Answer (score 1):

From what I see in the documentation, you have correctly pointed to the location of ckfinder.html and that's all you need. Here is a  link https://docs.ckeditor.com/ckfinder/ckfinder3-net/integration.html